# Give top priority to one Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four Ajax calls in my page. I always want to give first priority to first ajax call and all other ajax calls should wait until the first ajax completed even if it invoked . Is there any way where we give first preference to first ajax call?

Ajax 2 and Ajax 3 will be triggered on click of button. we can not put Ajax 2 and Ajax 3 on success of ajax call

```
//ajax 1
    $.ajax({
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: //URL
    })
 //ajax 2
    $.ajax({
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: //URL
    })
 //ajax 3
    $.ajax({
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: //URL
    })
 //ajax 4
    $.ajax({
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: //URL
    })
```

Comment: Put AJAX calls 2, 3, and 4 within the callback of the first one. *However* you shouldn't really be making multiple AJAX calls like this. Convert your logic to make a single call which sends and receives all required data.

Comment: ajax means basically asynchronus. if you want to queue your ajax call use queue or do async:false

Comment: @KarthickKumar ***never*** use `async: false`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you explain bit more behind not using async:false

Comment: Ajax 2 and Ajax 3 will be triggered on click of button. we can not put Ajax 2 and Ajax 3 on success of ajax call

Comment: syncronous ajax requests are a terrible user experience as they lockup the browser until the request is finished.  You should never freeze up a browser for any reason.

Comment: we should wait till first ajax calls completes. since the first ajax is updating certain data in db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just fire up rest of the calls when the first resolves:

```
$.ajax( ... )  // First AJAX
  .then(function(response) {

    // Play with the response of first AJAX operation        

    return $.when([
      $.ajax( ... ), // Second AJAX
      $.ajax( ... ), // Third AJAX
      $.ajax( ... )  // Fourth AJAX
    ]);
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    // Play with the response of rest of the AJAX operations.
  })
```

Comment: Ajax 2 and Ajax 3 will be triggered on click of button. we can not put Ajax 2 and Ajax 3 on success of ajax call

Comment: @ezhil -- you didn't mention it earlier.

Comment: @31piy thats no excuse!

Comment: @Pogrindis -- the requirements are still not clear to me to modify my solution. What OP mentioned earlier, this solution perfectly suits the requirements. Later, if he changes the requirements altogether, modification of the solution requires significant efforts.

Comment: @31piy relax, I am just being facetious ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of the `Done` method.

```
// ajax 1
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: //URL
}).done(function() {
    // ajax 2
    // ajax 3
    // ajax 4
});
```

For more details, view the API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you perform `ajax1`,  save the returned promise to a global variable ( let's say `ajax1Promise` ).

On button handlers of 2 and 3 use this code:

```
ajax1Promise.done(function(){ajax2()});
ajax1Promise.done(function(){ajax3()});
```

respectively.

**update:** Providing an example. I simulate ajax by returning custom promises with delayed resolution. Just check console logs:
https://jsfiddle.net/1gopxj49/13/

In this example if `ajax2`/`ajax3` are started while `ajax1` is in progress they will wait until it is finished.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I should replace settimeout with actual ajax call right? Also for me the ajax call will add on page load, no user interaction.

Comment: Yes. Also The returned promise is what `$.ajax()` actually returns.

Comment: Marinos, Sorry, I am little confused with settimeout and ajax here. Could you pls help me to understand on this? actually console.log("ajax1 complete") is not coming for me. I just placed my code in https://jsfiddle.net/ezhilre/frL7qwge/3/ Can you pls take a look?

Comment: In the example you provide you have not even included `jQuery` (resources section on the left). Please check the console for errors.